# popup image not working in html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the below code I am displaying a gallery that contains images. When I click on an image, I want to show the same image in a popup, and I also want to show the next and previous images. Any idea what my mistake was?

But it was displaying as a new window.

Can any one help me?

**html**

```
  <!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.pack.js?v=3.1.3"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

<!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

<!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<div id="Gallery">
   <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7501/15812584301_1d63602c58_b.jpg" title="elgol sunset (matty brooks)">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7501/15812584301_1d63602c58_m.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="113" />
</a>
<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8665/15613375844_99dc1e5dc0_b.jpg" title="Frondaisons (Valentin le luron)">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8665/15613375844_99dc1e5dc0_m.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="113"/>
</a>
<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7404/12868632153_b0a5718c22_b.jpg" title="The cold morning (Raimondas Ka.)">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7404/12868632153_b0a5718c22_m.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="113"/>
</a>
<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5584/15276294205_5a7ffe793c_b.jpg" title="Silhouettes (una cierta mirada)">
    <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5584/15276294205_5a7ffe793c_m.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="113"/>
</a>
     </div>
     </div>
  <script type="text/jscript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 50,
                height  : 50
            }
        }
    });
});
  </script>
```

Comment: you have an error: `sooperfish isnt defined` why do you have `$('ul.sf-menu').sooperfish();` in there?

Comment: that is for another one that one.

Comment: you have an error `TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function` are you loading the fancybox lib correctly?

Comment: where I am not getting

Comment: yes I am loading correctly

Answer (score 0):

Download these files from the url

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>-->


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
```

By appending the url http://fancyapps.com/ 
e.g http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5

and then include all these files in your project folder.
It will work :)

Comment: Please show me your project structure..I think your path used in scripts not correct

Comment: D:/mainfoldername/js/jquery.mousewheel.pack.js?v=3.1.3

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5 down load this js file and include it in your page

Comment: after downloading i was changed the path

Comment: No same it was opening image in new window